# Rate of Change Calculus Application question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, contest-math

My teacher gave us this unit assignment and its today. I'm so confused. What we learned this unit was everything about Rate of Change, limits, and derivatives. I'm panicking. If anyone can help with any semblance of a solution, I will be so thankful

questions: I need to catch my flight. I’m at the airport and I’m running late. I need to make it $1000m$ to get to my gate. I have two choices. I can either run or take the moving sidewalk. The moving sidewalk moves at a constant speed of $2 \frac{m}{s}$. If I’m running, I start out quick, but because I’m old I quickly tire and slow down.

Equations for these situations are:
$$M(t)=2t$$

$$R(t)=\sqrt{2000x}$$

I cannot run on the moving sidewalk because it’s too crowded, but I can to go onto or off of the moving sidewalk whenever I want to. Assume that I never recover my energy, so I can only have one burst of running.

How can I get to my gate in less than $500$s? Explain the process and determine the minimum time it takes me to reach the gate.

If the moving sidewalk moved at $2.5$ m/s, what is the best strategy and how quickly can I reach the gate?

If the moving sidewalk is moving at $2$ m/s, but running speed is modeled by $R(t) = 153(x2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, what is the best strategy and how long will it take me to reach the gate?

**For 1. I know that $M(t)$ is the distance traveled after $t$ seconds on the moving sidewalk.
$R(t)$ is the distance traveled after t seconds running.
I'm going to spend some time running and some time on the sidewalk, so I need to find possible values of $t_{0}$ and $t_{1}$ such that $M(t_{0})+R(t_{1})=1000$ and $t_{0}+t_{1}<500$. Then I am trying to minimize $t_{0}+t_{1}$ (the time it takes to get to your gate).
if you just run the whole way, or just take the sidewalk the whole way, you get there in $500$ seconds, so the problem is asking you to do better than that.
I'm just not sure how to translate this information into an equation. Once I can do #1 the #2, and#3 will be easy.
if you just run the whole way, or just take the sidewalk the whole way, you get there in $500$ seconds, so the problem is asking you to do better than that.**

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: One rule to arrive faster to a place is to go in the fastest way possible. How fast an object goes is measured in speed. Do you know how to calculate the speed of an object knowing how it moves? Do you think you could apply it here?

Comment: Next time, please edit your question instead of asking a new one.